# strong_parameters em Rails usando datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estou utilizando `strong_parameters` para criar um objeto de forma aninhada em um `form`. Todos os meus atributos funcionam corretamente, exceto os definidos em `datetime`.

Há algo de especial ao receber `datetime` aninhado?

Olhando o console, o atributo está sendo aninhado corretamente, mas ele vem com a especificação de `Ni`, com `N` de 1 a 6 dependendo de qual parâmetro ele se refere (ano, mês, dia...), mas ao criar o objeto (`INSERT INTO`), o atributo especificado em `datetime` não aparece:

```
Processing by ReleasesController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", ... "release"=>{ ... "qm_attributes"=>{"user_id"=>"1", "start_at(1i)"=>"2014", "start_at(2i)"=>"3", "start_at(3i)"=>"31", "start_at(4i)"=>"14", "start_at(5i)"=>"57", "end_at(1i)"=>"2014", "end_at(2i)"=>"3", "end_at(3i)"=>"31", "end_at(4i)"=>"14", "end_at(5i)"=>"57", ... }}, "commit"=>"Create Release"}

SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "qms" ("created_at", "release_id", "tipo_qm_release", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Descobri que o `datetime_selector` do html não funciona para objetos aninhados ao form. Quando eu passei a data por texto, tudo funcionou corretamente, fazendo o parse correto para `datetime`. Se alguém tiver dúvidas sobre todo o processo de utilização de `strong_parameters`, posso ser mais específico.